# Binding a doctrine_record class to a query result

Tags: php, doctrine

I just started out with Doctrine and it has been awesome so far. I have a little challenge though.

```
class TestTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
    public function getRecent()
    {                
        return $this->createQuery('Test')->execute();    
    }   

}

class Test extends Doctrine_Record
{
   public function setTableDefinition()
   {
       $this->hasColumn('test_id', 'integer');
       $this->hasColumn('user_id', 'integer');
       $this->hasColumn('date_registered', 'timestamp');
   }

   public function getDateRegistered()
   {
       return 'formattedDate';
   }
}
```

Calling the getDateRegistered function results in an undefined method error. Coming from a Zend Background, This is taken care of by writing your table queries like this

```
$table = new Zend_Db_Table(array('name'=>TableConstants::AUTH_CODE,'rowClass'=>'AuthCode'));
  return $table->fetchRow($table->select()->where('id = ?',$id));
```

Can I do something Like this in Doctrine? Specifying the Row Class while querying the table? Thank you

Comment: Ok, I noticed that the problem has to do with the field i was trying to access, a 'title' field, if I change the field however, it works well..i dont understand why it doesnt recognize the title field as I defined it in the table definition